# Docker machine inject USB device

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm currently creating my own docker image, and I'm trying to inject a USB camera device into my docker container. After searching/finding a lot of different answers, I've managed to do this.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /dev/usb/bus:/dev/bus/usb -t kerberosio
```

As I work on OSX, and thus using docker-machine, I forwarded the USB device into my VM, installed usbutils and there it is: my USB devices are visible to the docker image.

```
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/12p, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=, 12M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=, 12M
```

My next step is to actually use the USB camera (on Port 1 and/or Port 2). However when trying to open these devices with e.g. fswebcam. I get an error:

```
# fswebcam -d /dev/bus/usb/001/002
--- Opening /dev/bus/usb/001/002...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/bus/usb/001/002 opened.
/dev/bus/usb/001/002: Not a V4L2 device?
Trying source module v4l1...
/dev/bus/usb/001/002 opened.
/dev/bus/usb/001/002: Not a V4L device?
VIDIOCGCAP: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/dev/bus/usb/001/002 closed.
Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/bus/usb/001/002.
```

So fswebcam found the device but doesn't know how to handle it. After doing some more research I've found out that the drivers are not found (see output above lsusb -t).

I'm wondering if someone can help me and tell me how to tackle this problem. Do I need to install the drivers myself, if yes, how should I do it? I'm pretty sure this has something to do with a docker-machine configuration.

My setup:

- OSX 10.10.3
- Docker version 1.9.1

Thanks in advance!